# Flask - Bad Request Error on Form Submit

Tags: jquery, python

I'm trying to submit an HTML Form using Flask. But, it's giving me bad request error (400). I cannot figure out what's the issue. 
**Here is my HTML code:**

```
<div class="modal-body">

                <!-- content goes here -->
                <form class="add-user-form" name="add-user-form">
                    <div class="form-group" >
                        <label for="username">Email address</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Enter email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="brandName">Brand Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="brandName" id="brandName" placeholder="Brand Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="status">Status</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="status" id="status" placeholder="Status">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="msgDashboard">Message on Dashboard</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="msgDashboard" id="msgDashboard" placeholder="Message on Dashboard">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="reportAccess">Report Access</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="reportAccess" id="reportAccess" placeholder="Report Access URL">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default add-user" name="add-user">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
```

**And here goes the JQuery part:**

```
$('.add-user').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/add-user',
            data: $('.add-user-form').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                window.location.href = 'dashboard';
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
```

**Here is my Flask Code:**

```
@app.route('/add-user', methods=['POST'])
def add_dashboard():
    if 'username' in session:
        user_info = DashboardUser(session['username'], db)
        user_info.add_user(request.form['username'], request.form['password'],
                           request.form['brandName'], request.form['parentCompany'],
                           request.form['status'])
        user_info.add_dashboard(request.form['username'], request.form['reportAccess'], request.form['msgDashboard'])
        return "Success"
```

Can anybody help what i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: In mu flask code, I have mentioned the route.

Comment: It's 400 not 404 so I am pretty sure that route exists. @raushankumar

Comment: What happens if you add an else case for the `add_dashboard` function? Do you see the error logged in the console?

Comment: i have called another function in the else statement. which never executes there.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think your issue is that you are just returning a string "Success" instead of returning some kind of true web response.

You should use the Flask `make_response` method:

```
from flask import make_response

@app.route('/add-user', methods=['POST'])
def add_dashboard():
    if 'username' in session:
        user_info = DashboardUser(session['username'], db)
        user_info.add_user(request.form['username'], request.form['password'],
                           request.form['brandName'], request.form['parentCompany'],
                           request.form['status'])
        user_info.add_dashboard(request.form['username'], request.form['reportAccess'], request.form['msgDashboard'])
        return make_response("Success")
```